# mysql - Get birthdays from current week

Tags: mysql

I would like to find all the people that have their birthday in the current week.

For example, we are tuesday now, so i want all the birthdays from yesterday (monday) till sunday.

I have tried the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `employees` WHERE WEEK( birthdate ) = WEEK( NOW() )
```

But this is not giving me the correct data, as i also ge records where the birthdate is `1975-03-29`, which is next week and not the current week.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add the year difference to the birthday:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `employees` 
WHERE WEEK(NOW()) = WEEK( birthdate + INTERVAL (YEAR(NOW()) - YEAR(birthday)) YEAR )
```

But this will not work correct for the first and the last week of the year. So you would need to calculate the dates of this weeks monday and sunday.

Birthday this year:

```
SELECT e.*, birthdate + INTERVAL (YEAR(NOW()) - YEAR(birthdate)) YEAR
FROM employees e;
```

This weeks monday:

```
SELECT DATE(now() - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(NOW()) DAY);
```

This weeks sunday:

```
SELECT DATE(NOW() + INTERVAL 6 - WEEKDAY(NOW()) DAY);
```

Final query:

```
SELECT *
FROM employees
WHERE DATE(birthdate + INTERVAL (YEAR(NOW()) - YEAR(birthdate)) YEAR)
      BETWEEN
      DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(NOW()) DAY)
      AND
      DATE(NOW() + INTERVAL 6 - WEEKDAY(NOW()) DAY);
```

Demo: http://rextester.com/GCC50147

There is still an issue with the 02/29. This query will "say" the birthday this year is on 02/28. While it should probably be on 03/01. To fix that issue you can use the following "trick":

```
SELECT e.*, birthdate - INTERVAL 1 DAY + INTERVAL (YEAR(NOW()) - YEAR(birthdate)) YEAR + INTERVAL 1 DAY
FROM employees e;
```

Demo: http://rextester.com/WHI96898

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
 nama , 
 tanggal_lahir 
FROM 
 m_pasien 
WHERE 
 MONTH(tanggal_lahir) = MONTH(CURDATE()) AND 
 DAY(tanggal_lahir) >= DAY(CURDATE()) AND 
 DAY(tanggal_lahir) <= DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY);
```